# TIME complexity as the code doesnot works on large Input

Tags: python, python-2.7

I don't know why time limit exceeds for large inputs in this program (python).

Can anyone explain ??

Is it because of `ZIP` function?

I have used the ZIP  function . This program runs only for small input files

Following is the code:

```
for i in range(input()):
x=[]
y=[]
l=[]
ans=0
z=0
for j in range(input()):
    a,b=map(int,raw_input().split(" "))
    x.append(a)
    y.append(b)
    l=[list(l) for l in zip(x, y)]
    qq=[list(qq) for qq in zip(x, y)]
l.sort()



x_max=int(max(x))
x_pos=x.index(x_max)+1
x_min=int(min(x))
x_posmin=x.index(x_min)+1
y_max=int(max(y))
y_pos=y.index(y_max)+1
y_min=int(min(y))
y_posmin=y.index(y_min)+1
for k in range(len(x)):
    if(x[k]==x_max and y[k]==y_max):
        print "1"
        print "%d SW"%(k+1)
        z=1
        break
    elif(x[k]==x_max and y[k]==y_min):
        print "1"
        print "%d NW"%(k+1)
        z=1
        break
    elif(x[k]==x_min and y[k]==y_min):
        print "1"
        print "%d NE"%(k+1)
        z=1
        break
    elif(x[k]==x_min and y[k]==y_max):
        print "1"
        z=1
        print "%d SE"%(k+1)
        break

if(z==0):
    print "2"
    o=l[0]
    n=l[-1]
    kk=qq.index(o)
    zz=qq.index(n)
    if(o[1]<n[1]):

        print "%d NE"%(kk+1)
        print "%d SW"%(zz+1)
    else:
        print "%d SE"%(kk+1)
        print "%d NW"%(zz+1)
```

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by "time limit exceeds".  Also the indentation in your code appears to be messed up.  Which is a problem in Python.  Is the second assignment to `l` inside the loop?  Why?  What is `qq` for?  Why is that in the loop too?

Comment: Well I agree with strubbly, and your code don't even work if I try to launch it